# RegEx - Select words that are not tag names or attributes

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to select all words, that are not tags and not inside tags as attributes? I have got this working inverse, and I know I could make this in two phases, replace first matches and make a new Javascript RegExp search. But thing is that I'd like to get it work with one expression.

http://regexr.com/3cb6g

```
(<[^>]*>)|({[^>]*})
```

Input:

```
<p>Test image captions for GitBook:</p>

<p>Second image: <img scr="./image2.png" alt="image title" title="image title">asdf</img>{caption width="300" style="height:'300px'"} </p>

<p>Sample text and first image: <img scr="./image1.png" alt="image 1" /> {caption width="300" style="height:'300px'"} for testing ok...</p>
```

Expected output marking words inside ` that should be matched:

```
<p>`Test` `image` `captions` `for` `GitBook`:</p>

<p>`Second` `image`: <img scr="./image2.png" alt="image title" title="image title">`asdf`</img>{caption width="300" style="height:'300px'"} </p>

<p>`Sample` `text` `and` `first` `image`: <img scr="./image1.png" alt="image 1" /> {caption width="300" style="height:'300px'"} `for` `testing` `ok`...</p>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: too bad javascript/nodejs regex doesn't support negative loopback...

Comment: JavaScript supports negative lookaheads though. You can try reversing the string you're working on and reversing the order of the literal characters you're matching, then use lookahead in a reverse fashion. You might be interested in http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Comment: Thanks for good resources, they will be useful when studying regex secrets! I posted my solution as an answer because I happened to find the solution after asking the question. Preceding multiple hours of testing before the OT of course.

Comment: Yeah, but I still wouldn't attempt to parse HTML with RegExp. There are many malformed HTML structures out there which can easily corrupt any RegExp logic since the HTML needs to be cleaned first to convert mismatching tags, angle brackets, mis-matching quotes, mismatching script tgs, etc. Then once the cleaning is done, converting noise to entities, you can expect to be working on a structure that plays nicely for RegExp to parse. Even-still, it can get complicated. I would suggest using something like http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Comment: Thats true indeed. But I have control over my html in this case, so I can use this solution pretty safely.

Answer (score 1):

My question might not have been too clear because answers were using javascript code to process matches. My purpose was to find solution with simple expression only. I finally found this expression that satisfies my needs:

```
((?!([^<]+)?>)([\w]+)(?!([^\{]+)?\})([\w]+))
```

http://regexr.com/3cb6j

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var words = [];
$(function () {
  $("p").each(function () {
    words.concat($(this).text().split(" "));
  });
});
```

Now `words` array contains all the words.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.textContent` , `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\{.*\}|:|\.+|\s{2}|\s$/gi`

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p"), res = [];
for (var text = "", i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  res[i] = p[i].textContent.replace(/\{.*\}|:|\.+|\s{2}|\s$/gi, "")
}
console.log(res)
```

```html
<!--
<p>`Test` `image` `captions` `for` `GitBook`:</p>

<p>`Second` `image`: <img scr="./image2.png" alt="image title" title="image title">`asdf`</img>{caption width="300" style="height:'300px'"} </p>

<p>`Sample` `text` `and` `first` `image`: <img scr="./image1.png" alt="image 1" /> {caption width="300" style="height:'300px'"} `for` `testing` `ok`...</p>
-->
<p>Test image captions for GitBook:</p>

<p>Second image: <img scr="./image2.png" alt="image title" title="image title">asdf</img>{caption width="300" style="height:'300px'"} </p>

<p>Sample text and first image: <img scr="./image1.png" alt="image 1" /> {caption width="300" style="height:'300px'"} for testing ok...</p>
```